# lambda in vpc not able to access rds in peer vpc for same account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, vpc

Scenario
My lambda exists in one VPC and RDS exits in another VPC. Both VPC are in same account. 
I have peered them successfully. My EC2 in requester VPC can access EC2 in the second VPC.

But my lambda is not able to access RDS in peer VPC. I added the security group of lambda-VPC in security group of RDS-VPC. Also added subnet IPs in RDS-VPC security group. but no success.
Also when I printed the network interfaces it prints 192.168.... however my lambda subnet is 10.0...

The Requester Ec2 is in lambda subnet and using same security group. In RDS-VPC my EC2 is using RDS subnet and security group of RDS.

my lambda-VPC in which ec2 exists can access other Ec2 in RDS-VPC. but lambda is not able to communicate.

Note: If I open the RDS security group to 0.0.0.0/0. Then lambda can fetch data easily.

Comment: Does your RDS have "publicly accessible" configured?  If so, this suggests a DNS misconfiguration in the VPC peering setup.

Comment: yes its publicaly accessible. so from where i should change settings. from peering connction. Can you share some link. to solve this. thanks

Comment: You're probably resolving the public endpoint, then, which explains why `0.0.0.0/0` works.  To allow public/private split horizon across peered VPC, you have to enable it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/PeeringGuide/modify-peering-connections.html#vpc-peering-dns  Check this?